# Undefined parameter in Google Action

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have a DialogFlow agent I am trying to test on Google Assistant. I've created a relatively simple Intent called "Set name" with the following Training phrases:

- My name is Ryan.
- Bill
- I'm Steve
- The name's Bond. James Bond.

It has two parameters:

- Required: `given-name` with the Entity `@sys.given-name` and the value stored as `$given-name`
- `last-name` with the Entity `@sys.last-name` and the value `$last-name`

I'm able to test in just fine in the DialogFlow test console. But when I try to "See how it works in Google Assistant." I get the following error:

> Request contains an invalid argument. The query pattern 'The name's
>   Bond. `$SchemaOrg_Person:given-name` `$SchemaOrg_Person:last-name`.'
>   contains an undefined parameter '`last-name`.'

If I delete the "James Bond" training phrase, it works okay. But I would like to include that. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a screenshot of the intent that is causing the problem:

[image: troublesome intent]

Here is the link I'm clicking to try in Google Assistant:

[image: Open in Google Assistant]

And finally, here is the error message that appears in the bottom-right corner of the screen when I click that link:

[image: Error message pop-up]

Comment: Can you update your question with a screen shot of the intent in question? Is this intent set as a welcome intent?

Comment: @Prisoner The screenshot is now included. It is not set as the welcome intent. Just a regular old intent.

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate the error. Can you also include a screen shot of where the error is generated? What are all the steps to produce the error?

Comment: I am currently facing the exact same issue.

Comment: If you remove the second response at the bottom can you still reproduce it?

Comment: @NickFelker Yes, it still happens without the second response. I actually created the second response to see if I could get the error to go away.

Comment: Can you rename the parameter to something without hyphens? `last-name` to `lastName`

Comment: I am having a similar issue.   I am seeing the undefined intent for a phrase that doesn't exist.  It complains about a schema number doesn't exist just because i am using the word score in my phrase.  Even after removing the phrase and intent is is still there.

Answer (score 1):

I suddenly got a few of these error messages when both clicking the *"See how it works in Google Assistant"* link and submitting the app for production.

**It seems like characters like apostrophes and hyphens in the training phrases creates trouble** and can give that error message.

In addition it complained about a variant of the training phrases that I could not find anywhere no matter how much I looked at all languages, all pages of the phrases and all intents. **I finally found the phrase in question by exporting the project and searching through the JSON files. Then I could delete the phrase locally, delete the intent in Dialogflow and do an import back to Dialogflow.** (From my understanding it had messed up a follow-up intent which it also in the JSON (nowhere in the UI) had attached parts of some training phrases.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the dot from the sentence. So it will be:

```
"The name's Bond. James Bond"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same error and finally it was found to be an issue with the additional language I have added.

There was default "en" language and "en-IN" added by me. The issue was with training phrases in "en-IN" language. I didn't need it so removed it and it worked fine.

So, do check how many languages are enabled in your agent and whether training phrases are set properly for them or not.